# Editing value in a multiline-string numerous times and creating numerous new strings?

Tags: python, string, loops, for-loop

I'm using a python-based software, which utilizes long multiline-strings to run. I would like to create a loop in which I change one value to e.g. 40 other values and create 40 new strings where everything is the same except the target value.

I've achieved "what-I-want" as an output through this code:

```
for x in range(0, 40000, 40):
for line in mystring.splitlines(keepends=True):
    line = line.replace("24000", str(x))
    line = line.strip()
    print(line)
```

and it prints all 40 of the long strings, but how can I save them to new strings and use them in the software?

I could also achieve 1 iteration but only 1, through this code:

```
for x in range(0,40000,40):
   mystring = mystring.split("\n")
   mystring[17] = "Constant = " + str(x)
   mystring = "\n".join(mystring)
   print(mystring)
```

Hope my question makes sense. I would just like 40 (in this example) new strings identical except the one value changing throughout.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or if You want to save the output in to a new string:

```
output_string = ""
for x in range(0, 40000, 40):
    for line in mystring.splitlines(keepends=True):
        line = line.replace("24000", str(x))
        line = line.strip()
        output_string += line + "" 
              # beetwen quotation marks you can put the string with 
              # which You would like to split every line.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the new string values in a list. Changing your first example would look something like this:

```
output_strings = []
for x in range(0, 40000, 40):
    for line in mystring.splitlines(keepends=True):
        line = line.replace("24000", str(x))
        line = line.strip()
        print(line)
        output_strings.append(line)
```